# Is there a way to hide the upper and lower values in a NumberPicker

Tags: android

I want to use [this NumberPicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) (as the default one is not much customizable), but I want to hide the upper and lower level, showing only the center row...is this possible?
I also tried to remove the fadingEdges but, as I read, it's a deprecated attribute; even overScrollMode doesn't work

Comment: See may answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004336/android-picker-hide-upper-and-lower-value/43179722#43179722

Answer (score 6):

> I want to hide the upper and lower level, showing only the center
>   row...is this possible?

Looking at the source code, there are several things you could try. The easiest would be to change the following constant to `1`, since it controls the number items displayed in the selector 'wheel':

```
private static final int SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT = 3;
```

If that doesn't work, you could modify the drawing routine to skip over any index that isn't in the center row. You'll want to look at [lines 1468 - 1482](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker.java#L1468).

I'm not sure what you're trying to say about the fading edges, but if you're trying to remove them, it could be as simple as returning `0` in these two methods, at [lines 1426 - 1434](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker.java#L1426):

```
@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return TOP_AND_BOTTOM_FADING_EDGE_STRENGTH;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return TOP_AND_BOTTOM_FADING_EDGE_STRENGTH;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work; changing the fading edges values causes a weird fadeout of the number picker, while changing the SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT to 1 causes the application crash

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I find out there is no way to do it so... For them who want alternate solution.... I applied Viewpager instead of number picker to make it vertical i tried [link](https://medium.com/@jimitpatel/viewpager-with-vertical-swiping-ability-e40200094281) and applied Onpagechangelistner. Simply done...