# android picker hide upper and lower value

Tags: android, picker

```
numberPicker1= (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
final String genders[] = { "red", "blue", "green"};
    numberPicker1.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker1.setMaxValue(genders.length - 1);
    numberPicker1.setDisplayedValues(genders);

    numberPicker1.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);;
    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Value: " + genders[newVal], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

it disply random picker
how to hide previous one and next one value/string?

Comment: i have tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495601/how-to-hide-the-previous-and-next-numbers-in-a-number-picker) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770530/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-upper-and-lower-values-in-a-numberpicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I find out there is no way to do it so...
For them who want alternate solution....
I applied Viewpager instead of number picker to make it vertical i tried [link](https://medium.com/@jimitpatel/viewpager-with-vertical-swiping-ability-e40200094281) and applied Onpagechangelistner.
Simply done...

Sorry for those who are looking for solve issue For Numbericker!!

Comment: It's a bad idea because I want to display dates only in the number picker so you're suggesting that I have made 365 fragments for 365 days?